# What IP should I use in my .htaccess for exclusive access?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip, block, ip-address

I know there are alot of questions out there related to this, but mine is slightly diferent.

I may clear up that I am a junior in PHP (or less) and I am just dealing with new stuff. This is one of those.

Basically I want allow access to my admin folder in my server only to me. Which, I believe I can achieve through my IP. I found this to be put in the .htaccess file:

```
order allow,deny
allow from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
deny from all
```

Obviously, being the x's my public IP that I got from Google.

Now, when I try to access the folder with my computer it says "403 Forbidden" which means it kind of worked. But it is also blocking my IP. So, here comes my questions.

Is there more than one IP in a computer? If yes, which one should I use? How can I get it? What's the difference among them? What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be very apreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Also, I am not working on localhost. I am working remotely in the server I have uploaded my website to.

Comment: Your IP isn't blocked. 403 Forbidden means Apache can't access the folder your referring to because it doesn't have permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you going to acces from you own computer, you have to use your local ip, in windows you can find in the console using `ipconfig`, in unix systems `ifconfig`.

should be something like this

```
order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.0.1//127.0.0.1 or localhost
deny from all
```

Comment: This is true and really he could use `localhost` as well or `127.0.0.1` however in this case the error he's getting is a permission problem

Comment: @Cfreak When I started...not many years ago :).. I had several times the same issue and was for the ip...working on wamp and mamp

Comment: I am not working on localhost. I am working remotely in the server I have uploaded my website to.

Comment: @Cfreak : will 192.168.0.1 or localhost work if the access is done from somewhere else i.e. from some other PC via internet ? also in this answer 'from your own computer' means from localhost and not from internet I guess?

Comment: @sqlchild 192.168.x.x are intended only for your local network. The only way you could allow access from the internet would be to port forward on your router (if it supports such a thing). Generally not a good idea though.

Comment: @sqlchild and yes localhost would be from that computer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out. It seems the problem was the order.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from {mi_ip}
```

That works, with the other way around `deny all` seemed to overwrite the allowed IP

Comment: will 192.168.0.1 or localhost work if the access is done from somewhere else i.e. from some other PC via internet ?  like if I write this IP in deny then could the website be opened via internet?

Comment: The website can be accessed via another PC with another conexion. BUt the document I have applied this restriction to, cannot be.